# D3 equivalent of jQuery's child selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm looking for the D3 equivalent of jQuery's child selector, for example:

```
$('rect', this).addClass('active');
```

My use case is this: I want the `rect` element to toggle the `active` class whenever the user clicks on the parent `.bar` element.

```
<g class="bar">
  <rect height="18" width="300"></rect>
  <text class="label">Wholesale </text>
  <text class="value">679</text>
 </g>
```

Currently I have this:

```
bar.on('click', function(d) { 
 if (d3.select(this).classed("active")) {
  d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
 } else { 
  d3.select(this).classed("active", true);
 }
});
```

However, this is obviously applying the `active` class to the `g` element, not the `rect` as I would like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var bar = d3.select(".bar");
bar.on('click', 
       function(d) { 
           var rect = d3.select(this).select("rect");
           var hasClass = rect.classed("active");
           rect.classed("active", !hasClass); 
       }
);
```

Comment: I should note, I am not a d3 developer, I just happened to use the library once to play with it, there might be a better way. :)

Comment: +1, that's the way it's done. Though the OP could also make a CSS rule for `.active rect`